# Cannot show image as content of WPF ToggleButton

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm working at this Point of time with VS 2015 and WPF.
Some weeks ago i had defined in the App.xaml of my project a templated style for the ToggleButton, so that users can see, if the button is checked or not.
Originally the Content of the togglebutton was a TextBlock with a text.
Now i want to replace that textblock by an Image.
Further i defined in the App.xaml some resources for the Images.

Here is the App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WPFDesignerPrototyp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFDesignerPrototyp"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Style for togglebuttons-->
        <Style x:Key="toggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border x:Name="outer"
                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                Margin="5,5,0,0"
                                Opacity=".9"
                                Background="Transparent">
                            <Border x:Name="inner"
                                      Margin="5"
                                      BorderThickness="0"
                                      Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <Grid x:Name="container">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <!--<TextBlock x:Name="display"
                                               Grid.Row="1"
                                               TextAlignment="Center"
                                               Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               Margin="5,2,5,2"/>-->
                                    <Image x:Name="displayimage"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           Source="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                           Margin="5,2,5,2"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="outer" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="outer" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Image x:Key="imageHorizontalAlignmentLeft" Source="C:/Utilities/VS 2015 ImageLibrary/2015_VSIcon/AlignLeft/AlignLeft_16x.png"/>
        <Image x:Key="imageHorizontalAlignmentCenter" Source="C:/Utilities/VS 2015 ImageLibrary/2015_VSIcon/AlignStretchHorizontal/AlignStretchHorizontal_16x.png"/>
        <Image x:Key="imageHorizontalAlignmentRight" Source="C:/Utilities/VS 2015 ImageLibrary/2015_VSIcon/AlignRight/AlignRight_16x.png"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then - in my WPF window - i implemented the new Content into one of my togglebuttons.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="setAlignLeft" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{StaticResource imageHorizontalAlignmentLeft}" Style="{StaticResource toggleButtonStyle}" Click="setAlignLeft_Click"/>
```

But unfortunately nothing happens.
The Content of the button is blank.
So i tried it with another togglebutton, without the style toggleButtonStyle and there it worked.

I think there must be a mistake in my template but i don't know where.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance,
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to bind with `Content.Source` of the parent as `Content` is already Image.

```
   <Image x:Name="displayimage"
   Grid.Row="1"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
   Source="{Binding Content.Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
   Margin="5,2,5,2"/>
```

Comment: Thank You Nitin! That's the way it goes.